# SFTP transport as business service - how to dynamically change the destination folder?

Tags: oracle, sftp, osb, oracle-service-bus

I have a service bus project (on 12.2.1.0.0) in JDeveloper which polls file via SFTP transport (proxy service) and depending on file extension process should place it in directory1 or directory2. I have actually now configured SFTP transport also as business service however I am unable to find in documentation or in OSB a configuration for passing this dynamically changing output directory. I know I could use FTP adapter on weblogic, but that's "not" an option here due to the fact I do not have access to that weblogic and can not create it.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since the target directory is hardcoded in the URL, your only option, as far as I can tell, is to have 2 Biz services - each with its own directory in URL - and dynamically route to one or another based on your criteria.